# Overlapping networks at home and at work

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I have a strange problem that i'm struggling to resolve.

I have 10.0.0.0/22 subnet at work. Most of the fixed IP's are on 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.254. The rest are DHCP.

I have almost the same network at home, 10.0.0.0/24.
When I connected via FortiClient from home, I can't reach anything that is on the 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.254 pool, however, I can reach anything that is between 10.0.1.0-10.0.3.254 with no issue via all protocols.

I guess it's missing some kind of routing, please advice.

Thank you

Comment: P.S when i connected from other networks via VPN (phone hotspot, cafe's) I can reach all addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Your PC decides (correctly) that anything in the subnet 10.0.0.0/24 is locally connected to you and will not route packets down the VPN. This is normal behaviour.

You are a little unlucky, but the solutions to this are fairly complex. For instance you could use NAT to appear to be coming from a different subnet. This would be highly dependent your network knowledge and the capabilities of the VPN client.

If at all possible, the solution is to change the LAN subnet of your home network on your home router to something outside the range 10.0.0.0-10.0.3.255.

Comment: +1 agree, changing the home subnet would be the easiest and most logical.